# Lifting Analysis of a 3D cuboid

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, statics, force-measurement

I have a cuboid of weight W and the Center of Gravity at G. It is being lifted using 4 inextensible strings from the 4 corners: $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ and $C_4$. The figure is something like this:
[image]

The force is passing through the 4 strings, and I have to determine the value of the forces.
I know the coordinates of the lifting points $C_i$, the point where the strings are meeting $L$ and the locations of the center of the gravity $G$.

(Note: The $G$ is not located at the center of the body, so nothing is symmetrical. Also $L$ is just above $G$ to avoid any rotation).

Let the forces through each string be $F_i$. Performing force balance on the cuboid will give me 3 equations:
$$
  \Sigma \vec{F_i}.\hat{i} = 0 \\
  \Sigma \vec{F_i}.\hat{j} = W \\
  \Sigma \vec{F_i}.\hat{k} = 0
$$
Here $i$ in the subscript denotes the string number.

Taking the moments from $G$, gives us 3 equations as:
$$
  \Sigma \vec{GC_i} \times \vec{F_i} = 0
$$
So, in total I have 6 equations. On close inspection, I found the $M_y$ or y-component of $M$ is turning out to be 0. I still have 5 equations with 4 unknowns i.e., the 4 forces. I am not sure how to proceed on this. Any idea to proceed is welcome.

Comment: You don't have 4 unknowns, instead you have a total of 12 unkowns since tension in each string can be distributed into 3 of its components, one along each i.e. x, y and z axis. I don't think this should be possible to solve analytically by using the statics equation. A Rigid body module could be utilized in a FE sofware to compute the forces in each of the strings.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq: The 12 unknowns will come down to 4 unknowns again if we start relating the components of the force with the angles it makes with each other. The angles can be easily determined with the coordinates of the points given.

Regarding solving with FE tool, I have been solving this with Abaqus for a long time. However, if we can solve this analytically, there is no need to spend resources on FEA.

Comment: No, retake the course of statics or atleast revise this topic to replenish your brain with the basic idea which says that if you are writing equations in Fx, Fy and Fz, then you need to break down each of the tensions into its components along these directions, where each component of each tension (of each rope) will be an unknown, Ofcourse, you may simplify and narrow the unknowns down to only 6 (or maybe 9, as NMECH has iterated), by writing the few unknowns in terms of others (where this relation should be known beforehand).

Comment: Statics and analytical techniques work most of the times only for 2D cases, and if you are trying to apply these on a 3D problems then these problems should be extremely simple where number of unknowns matches the number of equations. This doesn't transpire most of the times and hence you then have to opt for FE tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important thing you need to account for in this problem is the fact that in the most general form of the solution, only three of the ropes will be in tension.

The above is always the case if you assume that the ropes are inextensible and if there is no symmetry in the problem.

The problem becomes more complex when you consider real life ropes (which can extend, i.e. they have a spring constant), but even then there are cases where one rope might have zero force.

---

In any case, in the general case, the workflow of the problem is the following:

1. you need to determine the position **and** orientation of the Cuboid so that the gravity center is directly below the support point

This can be done iteratively, by starting with the first two shortest ropes (there are some asterisks here if the gravity center is really close to one edge). Notice that **on each combination of ropes you will need to calculate a different orientation for the cuboid**.

2. once you have the orientation that 1 rope is slack, then you can proceed to solving the system of equations.

The equations are:

- 3 for the forces,
- 3 from the moments
- 3 from the resultant force and its components $F_i^2 = F_{i,x}^2+ F_{i,y}^2+F_{i,z}^2$

So, now the 9 unknown components (3 for each force $F_{i,x},F_{i,},F_{i,z}$, can be solved (a system of 9 equations and 9 unknowns if you use cartesian coordinates).

Comment: Your analysis is perfectly correct, considering the fact the cuboid is lifted using 3 strings. However mostly in physical world, a cuboid like system is lifted with 4 strings, and this problem makes the system mathematically indeterminate. What I am trying to use is some technique that can help us to solve indeterminate systems. Hope I am able to clear up the confusion.

Comment: So basically you are interested in the case where the ropes are extensible? (I only mentioned that case, because its much more complex, and I wasn't sure what exactly you were after - you might want to put this into your OP).

Comment: No, the ropes can be rigid bodies. However, in case you have 4 ropes (modelled as rigid bodies) attached, there will be forces passing through all the 4 ropes (unlike one rope being slack/ taking no force as you mentioned in your answer).

Comment: Ok, so you are really investigating rigid rods (instead of ropes) that can transfer compressive loads alongside tensile stresses?

Comment: Wait, by saying as rigid bodies, I meant it to be inextensible, not like rigid rods.

Comment: So there is a matter of interpretation here that you need to explain more clearly, in order to get a useful answer. A rope -even if it is inextensible (ie. infinite spring constant)- cannot resist compression (only tension).  Also, I must stress out that,  if the ropes are inextensible, in the general case the problem is statically indeterminate (i.e. you can hope to obtain a solution  only when 3 can carry loads).

Comment: Thanks @NMech for the suggestion. Added the detail of inextensible string in the problem. Also since the problem is statically indeterminate, can't we bring in some equations like compatibility equation to solve this?

Comment: Usually the compatibility equations in this context are related to strain equations (i.e. deformable bodies). So yes, you could use them if the bodies are deformable (extensible), however then the process would be an iterative one.

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively the same as a quadratic pyramidoid spaceframe.

You haven't specified the location of G except it is above the centroid.

The forces will be proportionately distributed among the lifting cables which will all be in tension by inspection. The compression forces will all be in the y plane so all that remains is to analyse this in the method of trusses. Since the moments to be examined will be internal forces of the object lifted, it is logical to start the analysis there. For each truss you need to consider that the forces to be examined are through the material and its surface. The strings to be ignored initially as they are a secondary issue and are only reaction forces.

I visualise the problem as a simple square pyramid with an off centre apex having a force applied vertically to the apex equivalent to its mass.

How this helps you find the solution. It's definitely statics using triangulated forces. Each hypotenuse force of the pyramid will be the exact same reaction force of the opposing string support. Newton's laws of motion